# Is get_validation_exclusions method of ModelSerializer in Django Rest Framework removed in latest versions?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

While running the below code:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(required=False)

    def get_validation_exclusions(self):
        exclusions = super(PostSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions()
        return exclusions + ['author']
```

I am getting the error `Column 'author' cannot be null`. When I checked online for documentation, this method is not available since 3.0 release (link: http://www.cdrf.co/3.3/rest_framework.serializers/ModelSerializer.html). Please let me know the alternative for this method supported in latest version.

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely want to set the [`allow_null=True`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#allow_null). `required=False`  will only work if the key isn't defined at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version, `required=False` fields are automatically excluded.
This is discussed in more detail in [this](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1257) (closed) issue.

I'd recommend updating to the latest version.